# Microsoft Report Viewer 2010 ClickOnce Install Problem

Tags: reporting-services, clickonce, reportviewer2008

We have a C# ClickOnce application. It needs to install the Microsoft 2010 Report Viewer. I have the 2010 Report Viewer selected as a prerequisite for the ClickOnce deployment. When the app is deployed to some machines (it doesn't happen with every machine), the install will stop with an error saying, "Unable to install or run the application. The application requires that assembly Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel Version 9.0.0.0 be installed in the Global Assembly Cache."

Has anyone experienced this? Also, why would 2010 Report Viewer be looking for v9.0.0.0 of this assembly and not 10.0.0.0?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

v9 is the internal version number of the dll.  2010 is the product name.  They are not related.